# websphere/wsadmin: how to specify third party provider in queue

Tags: jms, websphere, jython, tibco, wsadmin

In wsadmin, the command AdminConfig.create("WASQueue"... is to create MQ Queues and the command AdminTask.createSIBJMSQueue is to create JMS queues using the default JMS provider in Websphere...

However, how do we create a queue using a third party provider created using the command AdminJMS.createJMSProvider?

Answer (score 0):

Found it: there is a method createGenericJMSDestination in AdminJMS